# Codeigniter Issue route issue

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I want the following to happen

- The url something.com/why-us to go to content controller
- The url something.com/nepal to go to location controller

How to manage the above in CI routes

Answer (score 0):

Apply the below coding in routes.php in config folder

```
$route['why-us']    = "content_controller";
$route['nepal']         = "location_controller";
```

use your desire controller

Comment: nepal and why-us are dynamic content. so it can be tibet or india, even why-us can be why-choose-us.

Comment: $route['(:any)']  = "controller/$1"; any come, then redirect to one controller and check that get value

Comment: i have done it for $route['(((.+)$))?'] = "location/country/index/$2";
$route['(((.+)$))?'] = "content/index/$2"; works for content but not for location

Comment: Swap the places of routes. First `$route['(((.+)$))?'] = "location/country/index/$2";` than `$route['(((.+)$))?'] = "content/index/$2";` because of precedence. "Routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes will always take precedence over lower ones." [Docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html).

Comment: works for content controller but doesnot work for country controller if i do something.com/nepal , something.com/why-us both takes me to content controller.

Comment: Because both of same regex format, So CodeIgniter is get last given routing only. That is default concept in CodeIgniter.                   $route['(:any)'] = "common_controller/$1"; call common controller and second parameter separate the view file and functionality.